# Why can't I see my python.django.templates bundle in TextMate?

Tags: django, django-templates, textmate

I have just installed both the `python.django` bundle and the `python.django.templates` bundles for TextMate.  If I click on the Bundles menu item from the Mac menu bar at the top of my screen, I see them both in the drop-down menu.  However, at the bottom of my TextMate window I only see the Python Django option and not the Python Django Templates option.  Since I would like to declare that the file I am working on is a Django Templates file, this is annoying me.  Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type for Python Django templates is listed under **HTML (Django)**.